# why on git checkout it automatically adds changed files in my new branch

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have to checkout from one branch of the project to the other. When I do it, it adds all the added files in the changed branch also. I don't want to commit those files from this branch. What should I do and how should I avoid this thing in future

```
A   ui/.gitignore
A   ui/README.md
A   ui/babel.config.js
A   ui/package-lock.json
A   ui/package.json
A   ui/public/favicon.ico
A   ui/public/index.html
A   ui/src/App.vue
A   ui/src/assets/logo.png
A   ui/src/components/HelloWorld.vue
A   ui/src/main.js
Already on 'added_more_notification_channels'
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't.

Instead, what Git does is simpler:

- You already modified these files.
- You didn't *commit* these files.
- Therefore, these changes exist *only in your work-tree*.

You then asked Git: *Please switch from the commit at the tip of `master` to the commit at the tip of `added_more_notification_channels`.*  (I had to guess at one branch name, but it does not really matter much here.)

In some cases, Git will say: *Sorry, I can't do that: if I did that I'd destroy your updated files by replacing them with copies from the commit at the tip of `added_more_notification_channels`.*

In other cases, Git will say: *OK, I did that ... but **IMPORTANT NOTE: I didn't** destroy your updated files, I left them alone.  They now don't match the commit at the tip of `added_more_notification_channels`, just like they didn't match the commit at the tip of `master` before.*  If you had meant to add and commit them to `master`, you can now `git checkout master` again to get back to where you were.  If not, you're good where you are, with your modified files still modified.

If you're curious about *why* sometimes Git says: *OK, I've switched branches! (I took your modified files along for the ride!)* and sometimes says *Whoops, sorry, I can't do that!  That would destroy your modified files!*, see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).

(Actually, it looks like you asked Git: *Please switch from `added_more_notification_channels` to `added_more_notification_channels`*, which is no switch at all, and therefore always works!)

Answer (score 0):

If you `add/modify/delete` some files then you can get those files at another branch. So if you want to checkout another branch first you have to commit the changed files. Then you can checkout another branch. And if you don't commit, then you will get those file to the checkout branch.
So you should follow these steps -

- Add the changed files to git
- Commit this changes
- Push if needed (Optional)
- Checkout another branch